# Confusing Javascript Function and Parameter Declaration

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have just been looking at a tutorial for 3js scrolling animation control. Just saw in the example code that there's this strange function declaration with parameters set up that I've seen before. They look like key value pairs. When I copied and pasted the entire javascript code provided by the tutorial into my IDE and run it, it tells me that the ':' is unexpected. I was just wondering if this a valid format and get some more info how this code works.

```
function lerp( x: number, y: number, a: number):  number {
        return (1 - a) * x + a * y
    }
```

Comment: That looks like [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and not plain JS

Comment: Remove the typing from the typescript function to get the usual js function => `function lerp( x, y, a) { return (1 - a) * x + a * y }`

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%253Astackoverflow.com+js+colon+in+function+parameters) of [What does colon do in a javascript function parameter](/q/30610997/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly javascript, but [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

This syntax lets the interpretor know that `x`, `y` and `a` are supposed to be of type `number`.

Comment: PS: And that the function should return a `number` too.

Answer (score 0):

The function is declared in typescript you have to convert it into javascript in order to execute it directly or you can remove the type definations like this it then it will work.

```js
function lerp(x, y, a) {
    return (1 - a) * x + a * y;
}
```